# Integrating custom jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to front-end development and getting confused with jQuery. I have a jQuery slider with custom steps, but can't get the output to sync with the rest of my program. I think I need .addEventListener('input') to take the values produced by the slider so that the text at the bottom of the output (#infocenter) updates with the year chosen by the slider.

```
  document.getElementById('infocenter').innerHTML = '<p>(this text should update with the year above)</p>';


  var sliderAmountMap = [1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2009, 2015];

//new jQuery slider
  $(function() {
      $( "#slider" ).slider({
          value: 0,
          min: 0, 
          max: sliderAmountMap.length-1,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#amount" ).val(sliderAmountMap[ui.value] );
          }
      });
      $( "#amount" ).val(sliderAmountMap[$( "#slider" ).slider( "value")] );
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kaseyklimes/c0xpL1va/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you just need to update the `html` of the desired element at the same time you're updating the value of the text box:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
  $( "#amount" ).val(sliderAmountMap[ui.value]);
  $( "#infocenter" ).html(sliderAmountMap[ui.value]);
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0xpL1va/6/)